# Prove that the Number of 2-cycles is at most $k^2 k{!}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

How do I prove that the number of $2-$cycles on $ \{1,\dots, k \}$ is at most $k^2 k{!}$.

I know that a $2-$ cycle is a graph obtained either by joining two simple cycles by a simple path or by connecting two vertices of a simple cycle by a simple path.

But I am stuck on how to find the combinatorial formula. Any help or hint is appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: is $k^{!}$ a typo or notation?

Comment: @Phicar it's a typo I mean to say $k!$ thanks!

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with your definition of $2-$cycle in a graph (I'm guessing this is not a cycle of length $2$ as I expected/encountered before), could you define it?

Comment: @thibo The question was extracted from the **evolution of Random graph.** Connected components contains at most 1 cycle. And those cycles could be combinations of simple cycles. Either connected by a path or by vertices

Comment: @Serene are you talking about Erdös and Renly's evolution of random graphs or an other reference? Could you provide a precise pointer?

Comment: This definition of $2$-cycle sounds like it is a minimal connected subgraph whose cycle space has dimension $2$.